# Where is a user guide for Alfresco?

Tags: users, documentation, ecm, alfresco, nuxeo

Where is a user guide for [Alfresco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfresco_(software)) like exits for [Nuxeo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxeo): 
[Nuxeo Document Management: the User Guide](http://doc.nuxeo.org/5.2/books/nuxeo-user-guide/html-single/)

Comment: Is it not covered by their documentation and whitepapers in the Alfresco Community registration? http://www.alfresco.com/community/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an end-user manual [here](http://dsi.inria.fr/services_offerts/partage/user_manual.pdf), by Romain Delalande & Brice Chaffangeon.

Its a little old (2008), but seems fairly comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

Now there is [docs.alfresco.com](http://docs.alfresco.com/).

It is the official documentation, hope you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco maintains an introduction user guide, it is called [Alfresco in one hour](http://share.alfresco.com/share/page/site/community/documentlibrary#path=%252FWebinars%252FAlfresco%2520in%2520an%2520Hour&page=1) and is available in 5 languages, PDF or video. Unfortunately requires free registration.

More exhaustive is [Getting started with Explorer DM](http://share.alfresco.com/share/page/site/community/document-details?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/3d79d493-1389-4d77-b18b-5361e11551ea) which explains everything people need to use the Alfresco Explorer to do document management.

Answer (score 0):

If there is, and I suspect there will be as it appears to be selling itself as an enterprise-ready solution, it should be available under the product's website's documentation area ([here](http://www.alfresco.com/products/docs/)). It not, it might be worth registering with the product's own forum(s) and asking there.